# How to position float items relative to bottom of container DIV?

Tags: css, layout, web

I have a DIV (with non-fixed height) and I want some *float* images, a menu of my site, to be always positioned at fixed distance from the *bottom* of the DIV.

Code is like this:

```
<div class="header" id="header">

        <img src="img/aip.png" width="435" height="18" class="pageName"> <!--margin-top: 72px;-->
     <!--menu. Last item in line is 1st-->
        <img src="img/m-about.png" width="75" height="10"class="menu" >
        <img src="img/m-services.png" width="71" height="10"  class="menu"> 
        <img src="img/m-portraits.png" width="79" height="10"  class="menu"> 
        <img src="img/m-cosplay.png" width="65" height="10"  class="menu" > 
        <img src="img/m-concert.png" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
 </div>
```

where class "menu" says **"float:right"** AND contains **margin-top** parameter that sets position of menu from TOP of the "header" DIV. I achieve fixed position related to bottom via adjustments by JS on every resize. This does not work well: since height of enclosing DIV is variable (set in % of screen), I have to call javascript to compute pixel values and make adjustments to margin-top. It causes nasty side effects and jumps.

So, instead, I need a pure CSS to set position related to bottom of "header" DIV, not top of it. How can I do it?

CSS:

```
 .menu {
float:right;
margin-top:0px; /* adjusted by JS later so menu items have certain margin-top*/
padding:8px; 
padding-top:10px; 
padding-bottom:10px;
cursor:pointer
}

.header {
display: table-row;
background-color:#181818;
min-height: 114px;
 height:10%;
}
```

Comment: You should post the CSS also

Comment: #header {position:fixed;bottom:20%;left:0;}  something like that ?

Comment: Do you have any other content in the header? It looks like the header needs to be at least 18px tall based on your tallest image?

Comment: @suspectus: posted css. Header of course has min height.

Comment: Where do you want the `.pageName` element?

Answer (score 0):

### Working Prototype

The following might be a way of achieving this design:

The **HTML** could be:

```html
<div class="header" id="header">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/20" width="435" height="30" class="pageName"> <!--margin-top: 72px;-->
    <!--menu. Last item in line is 1st-->
    <div class="nav-wrap">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/10" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/10" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/10" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/10" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/10" width="68" height="10"  class="menu" >  
    </div>
</div>
```

I would wrap the menu/images in a wrapper and then absolutely position it with respect to
the parent container `.header` using the **CSS**:

```css
.menu {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 0px; /* adjusted by JS later so menu items have certain margin-top*/
    padding:8px; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    cursor:pointer
}

.header {
    background-color:#181818;
    min-height: 114px;
    height:10%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 960px;
}
.nav-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.pageName {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;    
}
```

You can float the images either left or right or use inline-blocks

If you want the `.nav-wrap` to shrink to fit the menu items, use `inline-block`, else `block` will also work.

For `.pageName`, I would pin it to the bottom left corner, add some offsets if needed.

I would also give `.header` a min-width value to make sure that the various images don't
overlap when you shrink the window size.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/vN3RQ/

Comment: Your placekitten site is great XD

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to wrap the menu images in a div (this is just as, if not more semantically valid IMO), then position that absolutely:

#### html

```
<div id="header">
    <img height="18" width="435"/>
    
    <div id="menu" class="cf">
        <img height="10" width="75"/>
        <img height="10" width="71"/>
        <img height="10" width="79"/>
        <img height="10" width="65"/>
        <img height="10" width="68"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
img {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#header {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 12px; /*note +2 for border, should be 10px really*/
    position: relative;
}

#menu {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:20px;
}

#menu img {
    float: right;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

See a [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/phkKJ/2/)

micro clear fix courtesy of [N. Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)